# How to resolve ArrayList does not take parameter

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have written the code and when I try to execute, it is giving error ArrayList does not take parameters. I have checked the code multiple times but unable to find any issue with it since I have my class name different than ArrayList.

```
class TestJavaCollection1
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    list.add("Ravi");//Adding object in arraylist
    list.add("Vijay");
    list.add("Ravi");
    list.add("Ajay");
    Iterator itr = list.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext())
    {
      System.out.println(itr.next());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should a type to the ArrayList, like this `ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Make sure it's `java.util.ArrayList`, then declare a non-raw type `new ArrayList<String>()` (the same with `Iterator`)

Comment: actually you should code against interfaces `List<String> meaningfulListName = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Thanks everyone. It is working now :)